# xcopy - Copy folder starting with a dot

Tags: windows, couchdb, xcopy

Hej,

Trying to copy the design-folders created from CouchDB on a Windows-machine Folder names start with a dot.

how is it possible to copy a folder (name starting with a `'.'` like `'.delete'`) with `xcopy`.

I tried

```
xcopy "path\to\folder\.delete\" "path\to\other\folder\.delete\" /e /i
```

but the . seems to be interpreted as wildcard.

Comment: A user is not allowed to name a folder starting with a dot in Windows. The system creates '.' and '..' ones but not the user. Hence, you don't xcopy those.

Comment: Okay, I understand, but do you know if it is possible to copy the design-folders created from CouchDB on a Windows-machine? Their names are starting with a dot.

Comment: Not really, I reformatted your question in case some one could answer it.

Comment: @EmmadKareem - "a user is not allowed to name a folder with a dot in Windows" is not a correct statement. It is easily accomplished from the command line. e.g. "mkdir .foo"  Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Almost done, just remove tailing backslash

```
xcopy "path\to\folder\.delete" "path\to\other\folder\.delete" /e /i
```